# associating post and user

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here are the three files associated with the original problem, I think...please excuse my ignorance...the rails generator does a lot of work for you, so I don't understand all the connections yet.

```
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

      has_many :comments
      belongs_to :user
      default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }

end
```

---

```
class AddUserToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer, :name 
    add_index :posts, :user_id  
  end
end
```

---

```
    class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.text :body
  t.text :name  #added this

  t.timestamps
   end
 end
end
```

---

> where the error is occuring:

```
     <%= link_to post.title, post %>
        </h4>
       <small>
          >> submitted 
          <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago by 
          <%= post.user.name %>  <br/>         
          <!-- <%= post.comments.count %> Comments  -->
      </small>
```

Comment: @sandipon:  Thank you for the cleanup, but where would I find the .name ?

Comment: You're getting the error because `post.user` isn't defined. Have you associated the Post and User models? How are you saving the post? Please post the controller action that you use to save new posts. For example, `posts#create`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby is basically telling you that on line 11 (`<%= post.user.name %>`) the `user` association of your `post` object is `nil` (i.e. a non-existent value, which in Ruby is a singleton instance of class [`NilClass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/NilClass.html)).

Thus you're trying to call the `#name`method on `nil`, that obviously has no such method, hence the `NoMethodError`.

Just add a check to make sure that user exists before printing its name `<%= post.user.name unless post.user.nil? %>` or make sure that there is always a user associated with your posts (e.g. through a [validation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence)), whatever fits best in your scenario.